# react-native package specifices a main module https module

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, npm

I made a test project, only trying to include https. I used `expo init test` to initialize the project, then `npm install https` to install the library.

I then edited App.js and included this line at the very top: `import {https} from 'https';`

Finally `expo start` to start the expo server.

Now I get the following error:

```
InternalError Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve module `https` from file `/path/test/App.js`, the package `/path/test/node_modules/https/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/path/test/node_modules/https/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * /path/test/node_modules/https/index.js(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
  * /path/test/node_modules/https/index.js/index(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
```

I've verified that these files do indeed not exist, here is the output of ls node_modules/https: `package.json`

So I'm guessing I did something wrong during the install process, however, I can't figure out what. (I've also tried several times to install using `yarn add https`, I got the same error)

Comment: Did you restart metro after installing ```https``` library?

Comment: @MaksymBezruchko yes.

Comment: Did you try to import it as default module: ```import https from 'https';```?

Comment: @MaksymBezruchko yes.

Answer (score 3):

The `https` module you want is almost certainly the Node.js built-in `https` module and is definitely not [the six-year-old `https` npm module with no documentation or code and merely a lone package.json file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https). That package should probably be deprecated so people don't make this entirely understandable mistake.

In short, try `npm uninstall https` and see if your code starts working. It probably will.

If not and you really need some external module, it's definitely not *that* module. Look at one of the many many great http/https modules out there. @Nitish suggests [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) in their answer and that is a popular and solid choice.

`import {Agent} from 'https';` should work with the built-in `https` module assuming you're working with a reasonably recent version of Node.js. (You can quickly test your version of Node.js for this by putting that line of code in an `index.mjs` file and running `node index.mjs`. If there's no error message, it worked.)

Disclaimer: I know nothing about `expo`. This is all from a Node.js/`npm` perspective.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I didn't realize those were 2 separate things. The problem is that I'm using react native, not standard nodejs, and react native doesn't include the node standard libs. I'm already using axios but it seems that I need https to pass axios and https agent to allow requests over self signed ssl. I'll keep looking for a different way to configure this.

Comment: @user12989668 Have you found solution? Can you share please?

Answer (score 1):

https is one of the core NodeJS modules which can't be use in react-native API client assuming that your App.js file is a frontend react-native code. Also, as https is a core module from nodejs, you don't need to install it separately if you have installed node.

Refer this https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Also, note for devs that never install any package from npm unless you read the details about it. eg. https is a waste package and it doesn't have any code in it so just be cognizant of it.

Answer (score 0):

the error is clear that your package.json don't have https module.
I don't know why you need this module but if you need this for REST API I suggest [fetch](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/react-native/network/) or if third party you can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: @b3nj4m1n Please let me know your requirement.

Comment: I am using axios, but I need to make a request over an ssl connection with a self signed certificate (I can't use a free online certificate authority) so from what I've read online, I need to create an axios instance and pass an https.Agent with rejectUnauthorized set to false. If there's any other way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest, you should ask another question for this issue specifically mention you want to do this in react-native app.